# Is the CSS right?

Tags: css, position, margin

Below is my CSS file and an image of what I'm referencing. In the picture, it's the 1st, but if it was the 10th, or any other 2-digit-day, would the 2013 or no? It's a dumb question, and I know, but I'm not sure about the whole margin, padding, position, and float factors.

REPHRASED QUESTION: I'm not too good with padding and margins so maybe I'm asking the wrong question. The picture shows April 1 2013, great. But I'm wondering if April 10 (a 2nd-digit day) will make the 2013 shift RIGHT (what I want), overlap the 2013, or go somewhere else not on that line? Reason I'm asking is because of my margins, paddings, floats, and positions, I'm not sure if it's going to affect it..

[image]

```
@font-face {

    font-family: Walkway Bold;

    src: url('Fonts/WalkwayBold.ttf');
}


@font-face {

    font-family: Roboto;

    src: url('Fonts/Roboto.ttf');
}

@font-face {

    font-family: CaviarDreams;

    src: url('Fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf');
}

body {

    font-family: Roboto;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    background: #000;
    background-size: 61%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:3px 3px 7px #000000;

}

div#content {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    left:75px;
    top:0px;
}

div#timecluster {
    font-family: Roboto;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:30px;
    left:-95px;
    color:#fff;
    clear:left;
    width:345px;
    opacity:.8;
}

div#hourbox {
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-align:right;
    color:#ffffff;
    position:relative;
    font-size:75px;
    letter-spacing:-5px;
    margin-right:3px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

div#minutebox {
    font-family: Roboto;
    position:relative;
    opacity: 0.2;
    font-size:75px;
    letter-spacing:-5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

div#ampmbox {
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
    font-size:75px;
    letter-spacing:-5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:-5px;
    right: -5;
}

div#datecluster {
    position:absolute;
    top:90px;
    left:-130px;
    width:380px;
    height:180px;
}

div#dateinner {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:40px;
    width:300px;
    height:90px;
}



div#monthbox {
    font-family: CaviarDreams;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    font-size:20px;
    opacity:0.2;
    width:135px;
    text-align:right;
    top: -19px;
}

div#daybox {
    font-family: CaviarDreams;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    font-size:20px;
    opacity:0.2;
    width:135px;
    text-align:right;
    top: 1;
}

div#datebox {
    font-family: Roboto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:-20px 4 0 10;
    font-size:40px;
    opacity:.8;
    text-align:center;
}

div#yearbox {
    font-family: Roboto;
    position:relative;
    float:none;
    margin:-20 0 0 0px;
    font-size:40px;
    opacity:.1;
top:0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: and I have no clue about what you are actually asking...

Comment: Maybe the question is: will the css works? What's problem you are facing?

Comment: Serendipitepic, you need to rephrase your question. Right now your post makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but in context your question is, some browser do not support the ttf fronts by default, so you may convert them to "woff" supports better,

use google fonts the are freely available, if that suits your requirements then :)

or convert your ttf fonts in woff, many free online converters are available,

then code will be like this.. for 'Droid Serif'

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Droid Serif Bold'), local('DroidSerif-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidserif/v3/QQt14e8dY39u-eYBZmppwTqR_3kx9_hJXbbyU8S6IN0.woff) format('woff');
}
```

I hope this will help you :)

With Updated Question

Add some margin to the year left,

Updated Answer..

```
div#yearbox {
font-family: Roboto;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:-20 0px 0px 10px; 'this last element will represent margin left i.e. 10px
font-size:40px;
opacity:.1;
top:0;
}
```

Comment: Hey MarmiK, thanks for replying quickly. I put that and it made the 2013 go all teh way left of the screen. I want it next to "1" of April, so would I change the "margin 10x" or the "right:0"? Both seem to do the same thing, but it still leads to the main question I put up on top about the "10" of April.

Comment: I know, but I still want to know if the "10" will overlap the 2013, shift 2013 to the right, or make it weird and have it displaced?

Comment: Day, Date and Year are relative so it will push it on the right, nothing else will happen, if you will make it absolute than the problem will arise, so keep it with same style 'position:relative'

Comment: Okay. and another thing, what's the difference between top:0 and right:0 when I have margin?

Comment: MarmiK, everything was great excet that now it's the 10th of April, and it's overlapping 2013. What do I change?

Comment: Try updated style of `div#yearbox` in answer above. changed `float:left` and remove `right:0`. that should do :)