# font-face does not work with Chinese font

Tags: css, font-face

As title already says: font-face does not work with my Chinese fonts.

I have downloaded some Chinese fonts, but for some reason these are not recognized by my css.
This is the css I use:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'chinese';
    src: url('chinese.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html {
    height:100%;
    font-family:"chinese";
}
```

Now, if I change the url to a 'normal' font, it works; also for downloaded fonts (I tested it with Din). Unfortunately the 'normal' fonts do not support Chinese, so the characters will stay unaffected.

Both fonts are located in the same folder as the css file, so the url is not the problem. Also all character sets are correct (or else I couldn't see the default Chinese at all).

Is there maybe some extra thing I have to do for Chinese? Or what is it?

Comment: what browser are you in? John Peter's answer below may help, but you're going to want to convert your font into multiple font formats for cross-browser compatibility....http://fontsquirrel.com/ has a generator you can use. if that doesn't work, apply John's advice

Comment: Please identify the origin of the font and/or provide a link to an online demo of the problem. (For example, it is possible that the font is not Unicode encoded.) Also check whether the font works in general (say, in Notepad) if installed in your system.

Answer (score 5):

When declaring a Chinese font family, it’s typically a good idea to type out the romanization of the font (for example, “SimHei”) and declare the Chinese characters as a separate font in the same declaration. What this does is help reference the font file regardless of weather it’s been stored in the local system under its Chinese or western name – you’re covering all your bases here.

***Example :***

```
font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, "Microsoft Yahei","微软雅黑", STXihei, "华文细黑", sans-serif;
```

**For Your Reference :** [Good Rules for Using Chinese fonts in CSS](http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/)

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

refer this post,

I think you need the same answer :)

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756093/is-the-css-right/15756147#15756147
```

convert fonts to "woff"

that will solve your purpose..

Sample :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Droid Serif Bold'), local('DroidSerif-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidserif/v3/QQt14e8dY39u-eYBZmppwTqR_3kx9_hJXbbyU8S6IN0.woff) format('woff');
}
```

you need to modify font name and url :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's a service based in Taiwan can help you use different Chinese font.

http://en.justfont.com/fonts

Due to the large size of Chinese font file, it's recommended to use Google cloud service. But there's no appropriate Chinese font on it. So you can give it a try on this justfont web font service.

1. Select any font you want for specific font weight. Then it'll be added to your project.
2. Choose your selector like `.notosans`, `#notosans` or `h2`
3. Click "JS" button and get your code for your setting
4. Add it befor `<body>`
5. Insert your class or id.

Give it a try and get your beautiful Chinese font. :)